# Difference between batch and column mode?

Tags: chromatography

I have heard Ion-exchange chromatography can be used in *batch* or *column* mode, have you got any idea how are those modes?

I have looked descriptions all over books and web (Skoog for example, both versions of analytical chemistry) but found nothing clear.

Any help?

Comment: Probably batch by batch or in continuous mode.

Comment: @Alchimista but what is an ion exchange by batch?

Comment: First the sample is made to bind than eluted. https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/ParimalaGattupalli/ion-exchange-chromatography-1-4